# How to preserve XMP metadata in Objective C?

Tags: metadata, xmp

I need my photo-editor app to preserve unknown metadata entries that were existing in the original photo that was opened by my app (for example, non-standard XMP meta-data)

I tried to use the Apple's built-in meta-data read/write meta-data, with no success.

Is there a way to just copy all existing meta-data to a buffer, write it as-is and then change only specific entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

- Use Adobe XMP SDK.
- Read the metadata from the image when you open it using:

  `SXMPFiles myFile;`

  `ok = myFile.OpenFile(filename, kXMP_UnknownFile, opts);`

  `myFile.GetXMP(_meta); // _meta is a data member of the class that represents your photo (probably a subclass of NSDocument).`
- When saving the image, write the image content, then write `_meta` to the output file using SXMPFiles.PutXMP(...), and then set specific metadata entries that you like.

See Adobe XMP programming guide for more details about reading and writing XMP metadata.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to write XMP metadatas to a video on iOS, with objective-C. Do you know if this SDK would work in my case ? If yes, do you know how to install it for Xcode ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: The XMP SDK works on many different formats and you can extend it for other format. I compile it as a static library and use it with Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, it compiles and I'm about to test it. However how can I do to open a file that is in the camera roll ? Do I need to copy it to an internal folder, and send this path to "OpenFile"?

Comment: If you have some spare time, can you please check my question here please ? That would be awesome, thanks in advance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342701/ios-read-write-xmp-metadatas-of-mp4-videos